# Blackberry: how to change size of font at browser field on OS 5.0?

Tags: blackberry

On all others versions of platform I use this:

```
BrowserFieldConfig cfg = new BrowserFieldConfig();
cfg.setProperty(BrowserFieldConfig.NAVIGATION_MODE,     BrowserFieldConfig.NAVIGATION_MODE_POINTER);
cfg.setProperty(BrowserFieldConfig.JAVASCRIPT_ENABLED, Boolean.TRUE);
cfg.setProperty(BrowserFieldConfig.CONNECTION_MANAGER, _browserAdapter);
cfg.setProperty(BrowserFieldConfig.COOKIE_MANAGER ,_browserAdapter);

browserField = new BrowserField(cfg);
browserField.getRenderingOptions().setProperty(RenderingOptions.CORE_OPTIONS_GUID, 
        RenderingOptions.MINIMUM_FONT_SIZE, fontSize);
```

, and it is works fine. However it doesn't work on 5.0 only.

Can you say where is a problem or suggest an another method to change size of font? All help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may consider to inject css rules in browserField as:

```
String style    = ""; // here css rules
String textBody = ""; // here your displaying text

String browserContent = "<html><style>" + style + "</style>" + textBody + "</html>";


byte[] contentBytes;        
try {
    contentBytes = browserContent.getBytes("UTF-8");
    browserField.displayContent(contentBytes, "text/html; charset=UTF-8", "");
}
catch (...) {
        ...
}
```

in this manner you may change dinamically text size (and other) just replacing the injected css style.